# mocha hangs after tests have finished

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm running mocha in nodejs, testing an asynchronous function, I didn't forget to call done, but after the test passes mocha just hangs there, waiting for nothing. Even the function that I placed for `after()` has finished, but mocha doesn't exit until I CTRL+C it.

Here is the code:

```
describe("tests the user_handler", () => {
  beforeEach(resetDB);
  after(resetDB);

  it("returns null when searching for a user with an id that does not exists", (done) => {
    userHandler.findUserById( {user_id: "U-1234567"} )
      .then((result) => {
        expect(result).to.be.null;
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

and here is the output:

```
tomk@tomk-Latitude-7480 ~/workspace/fundme/server (login_with_github) $ npm test

> fundme-server@1.0.0 test /home/tomk/workspace/fundme/server
> mocha tests/*.spec.js



  tests the user_handler
resetDB called
resetDB finished
    ✓ returns null when searching for a user with an id that does not exists
resetDB called
resetDB finished


  1 passing (64ms)

^CTerminated
```

If it's relevant (though I don't think so), the function being tested is using a promisified version of `mysqlConnectionPool` from the `mysql2` library

Here is the code for the `resetDB` function I'm using for the `beforeEach` and `after`:

```
function resetDB() {
  console.log("resetDB called")
  command =
    "mysql" +
    " --defaults-extra-file=" + mysql_conf_file +
    " --host " + process.env['MYSQL_HOSTNAME'] +
    " -D fundme < " + testing_db_file_location;
  cp.execSync(command);
  console.log("resetDB finished")
}
```

any ideas to what I might have forgot?

Comment: What does `resetDB` look like or do?

Comment: it executes a command that resets the mysql database to its initial state. I'll edit my question and add the code

Comment: Could you add something to your after that releases the connection pool?  Or are you sure it is actually release?  `pool.releaseConnection(conn);`  Judging by the [docs](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools) it seems like that may be critical.  The only other thing that I can think of is that the process you spawn may not be exiting.  Can you check whatever process monitor you use to see if that is the case?

Comment: you are absolutely right! that was it! I was thinking that if I used `mysqlConnectionPool.query()` without manually getting a connection and performing a query on it, it will handle the connection for me and will close it. That was silly if me. I added another after function that does `mysqlConnectionPool.end()` - that fixed it. Thank you

Comment: OK, I'm going to post that as an answer then.

Comment: Thanks for asking this and with so much context (code, error, description etc), I know that these sort of "hidden" processes have bitten me before as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you mention you are using a `mysqlConnectionPool`.  I'm guessing that you may not be closing out the pool which is causing your program to continue on waiting for all the connections to close out.

Judging by the docs: [Using connection pools](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools)

> `// Don't forget to release the connection when finished!`

releasing the connection after you are done is critical.  Check and make sure that you are doing this `after()` each or all of your tests:

```
// For pool initialization, see above
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
   // Do something with the connection
   conn.query(/* ... */);
   // Don't forget to release the connection when finished!
   pool.releaseConnection(conn);
})
```

Or, since this is only a test file, closing all the connections in the `after` will make sure mocha stops at the end:

```
after(() => { mysqlConnectionPool.end() })
```

Comment: So what if I'm not using a `mysqlConnectionPool`?

Comment: @AndrewKoster if you are using `createConnection`, I think there is an [`end`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#terminating-connections) method.